# Send a html table to php

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation, bootstrap-4

I create a table in a form but this is the only thing is not fetched.

Used **bootstable** to create this table.

The Table and some button controls of the cells making them editable and can add or delete row:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed  text-center" id="DyanmicTable" name="DyanmicTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Repère</th>
            <th class="text-center">Quantité</th>
            <th class="text-center">Segments</th>
      <th class="text-center">Fixations latérales</th>
      <th class="text-center">Dalle à gauche</th>
      <th class="text-center">Commentaires</th>
            <th class="text-center">
        <button id="addNewRow" class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Ajouter une ligne</button>

            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The script used to fetch the form and send it to PHP:

```
<script>
  const myForm = document.getElementById('msform');

  myForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData(this);

    fetch('test.php',{
      method: 'post',
      body: formData,
    }).then(function (response) {
      return response.text();
    }).then(function(text){
      console.log(text);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Where is the form?

Comment: When editable, does it have any input elements? A table itself cannot be submitted, even if put inside a form.

Comment: better title, text and code

Comment: My Source code is here  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Be_JfV3TjQqhn6TE7wUzrdtlzxdm5teZ

Answer (score 0):

i suggest using this function in your PHP code without catching errors

```
<? include('table.html') ; ?>
```